# Using Using OAuth 2.0 for existing Web Applications

Tags: java, web-applications, oauth-2.0

I need to integrate a functionality in a web app for uploading videos to YouTube. I have been reading documentation but still I am mixed up. More specific, I don´t know how to make the Authorization.

I have read that I have to provide concrete classes for `AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet` and `AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet`. But then, how do I reach them to make the authorization? Probably is pretty basic, but I haven´t worked with servlets too much.

Does anybody help me, please??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all I needed to do is call my concrete class of AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet. The token is in the response url.

Comment: do You have real example?